# how to make visual studio recognize certain keywords

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, syntax

I'm using cuda in C++, the cuda compiler "understands" certain keywords (i.e. **global**) but visual studio's syntax highlighter recognizes these keywords as errors, while this doesn't break anything, it's quite annoying.

is there any way to make visual studio recognize these keywords (no need to redefine them, just make visual studio understand that they exist).

```cpp
__global__ void func(int* a, int* b)
{
    int place = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        ///more code
}
```

Comment: By "errors", do you mean the Intellisense red wrinkly underline? There's also keyword coloring, and that's a different mechanism.

Comment: @MSalters yes, and an error in the "errors" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the compilers involved. Visual Studio has a fairly smart editor, with so-called Intellisense functionality. This editor includes a real C++ compiler - parsing C++ just isn't feasible without one. Now `__global__` isn't a C++ keyword, so Intellisense has every reason to complain.

As a workaround, since it's a real compiler, you can take advantage of that:

```
#if defined __INTELLISENSE__
#define __global__
#endif
```

Now the preprocessor of Intellisense will remove the `__global__` and compile the remainder as regular C++. Intellisense does not actually link, so there's no harm later on.

Comment: will the preprocessor remove __global__ from the code or just what intellisense sees, after all I do need that keyword so nvidia's compiler will compile correctly.

Comment: @GideonMax: That's why I stress that there are multiple compilers. The preprocessor of the Intellisense compiler is not the same as the preprocessor of the CUDA compiler. The former will remove it, the latter won't. Obviously that could be dangerous, because it means the two are not compiling exactly the same code. But in this particular case, it's OK.